# Google Endpoint on personnal server

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-endpoints

I've read some things about Google Endpoints : https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/about-cloud-endpoints?hl=fr&_ga=2.253675593.-1966596577.1507026460

But I'm not sure : 
Is it a thing only available on Google Cloud, or is it possible to have a Google Endpoint system on another server ?  For example in my personnal server to protect my APIs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Endpoints proxy outside of GCP. Note that it does communicate with Google services for a lot of its features, so the location may impact performance.

Comment: Do you have a reference, example, or proof-of-concept besides the source? One might as well claim that it's not feasible.

Comment: I work on the Endpoints team, so my claims hopefully have more weight. I don't have a proof of concept for you, but it is definitely possible to run the proxy locally using Docker. It should be pretty similar to running on GCE.